# How to dismantle Campag Ergolevers (hex key won't turn)

Tags: shifter, campagnolo

Following my recent question [Overhauling 1998 Campagnolo Chorus Ergolevers](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52281/overhauling-1998-campagnolo-chorus-ergolevers), I attempted to take apart the right hand lever. But I got stuck at pretty much the first hurdle: undoing the bolt that retains all of the inner workings. Using two hex keys, one from the back and one from the front, and lots of force (enough to round off a cheap hex key!), the bolt would not budge.

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a known problem with these sometimes seizing? If so, any ideas about freeing the seized part?

Comment: Righty-tighty, lefty-loosey.  (Usually)

Comment: They have normal right-handed thread. If I recall correctly the screws are secured with blue loctite, so carefully heating the mechanism might help. And you probably figured this out, but turning the front is limited by the mechanism, the smaller screw at rear is the one to be unscrewed.

Comment: @ojs - I have been attempting to turn the screw at the rear against the screw at the front with a hex key in each. Should I instead be turning the screw at the rear against the body of the ergo?

Comment: You can do it both ways, the key in front is needed to keep the axle from sliding forward when the screw at rear is removed.

Comment: Are you sure it's a HEX allen key you need and not a Torq (Star) 25mm key? That's what I used to undo mine, but mine are 2008 models.

Comment: Update: Applied gentle heat then tried again. Knowing that this was a last-ditch attempt to prolong the life of these 20 year old shifters, I set up a rig that allowed a great deal of torque to be applied. I broke the plastic body of the shifter :-( Oh well. I think the bolt was well and truly seized. Nothing ventured...

Answer (score 1):

From my experience (see below) since asking the questions, the answers are:

- Am I doing something wrong? **NO**
- Is there a known problem with these sometimes seizing? **YES** - known now by me!
- If so, any ideas about freeing the seized part? **YES** thanks @ojs for the suggestion.

My experience was that I broke the plastic body of the lever. This was because it was held in a vice and I was putting a great deal of torque (lefty-loosey, thanks @haniel-r-hicks :-) ) through the seized bolt in a last ditch attempt dismantle it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the version.

Oldest version with a 4mm allen head bolt in black is LEFT HAND THREAD ... all the more recent are standard RH thread.

As head tech at Campag's main UK Technical Centre I have never seen a seized bolt in an ErgoPower lever and we service between 10 and 15 a month at this time of year - I've done several 100 in the last 25 years, since ErgoPower was introduced ...

Comment: The version I have was as exploded [here, on page 41](https://www.campagnolo.com/media/files/035_184_Catalogue_pi%C3%A8ces%20d%C3%A9tach%C3%A9es_outils_Campagnolo_1998_partie_A.pdf). If these were left hand threaded, that would explain a lot!